# Calculate negative hours on php

Tags: php, datetime

I'm developing a script to measure the working hours.

For that, I have this functions:

```php
function somahora($HoraInicio, $HoraFim, $format = 'H:i') {
    if($dateStart != '0' AND $dateEnd != '0'){
        
        $d1 = new DateTime($HoraInicio);

        $d2 = new DateTime($HoraFim);

        $hh = $d2->format('H');
        $mm = $d2->format('i');

        //Calcula a diferença entre as datas
        $add = $d1->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $hh . 'H' . $mm . 'M'));

        //Formata no padrão esperado e retorna
        return $add->format($format);
    }elseif($HoraInicio == 0){
        return $HoraFim;
    }elseif($HoraFim == 0){
        return $HoraInicio;
    }else{
        $erro = 'Erro';
        return $erro;
    }
        
}
```

I need the function "somahora" to be able to work with negative values, so I can compensate for one extra hour with a negative hour, due to working less than the working journey.

Example:

```php
somahora("01:00", "13:00"); //RESULT: 14:00

somahora("-01:00", "13:00"); //RESULT: 04:57 | EXPECTED RESULT: 12:00
```

I am working with 24h format (00:00, 23:00, etc).

Comment: I didn't look at the other 2 function, since your question is only about `somahora()`. From your question it seems you're only adding times together, not dates? Then why call them dates? Can they be full dates? Do you want that to work as well? Also, please pay attention when writing code. Hours are stored in `$mm`, and minutes in `$ss`, why? Why not `$hour` and `$minute`? You add, but your comment says: _"Calcula a diferença entre as datas"_. You have a `$format` argument, but you don't use it everywhere.

Comment: Hello Kiko. You're right. Although I'm just testing some functions, I really have to pay more attention. I edited the post so it only shows the "somahora" function and I corrected the "dates" to "hours", etc.

About your question, the whole project works with hours (adding hours, subtracting hours, etc). It'd be great if there was a way to work with negative hours like this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @joaomontes The PHP class https://github.com/jspit-de/dt can work with tenses like "HH: ii".
Take a look at the addTime () and diffFormat () methods.
To give an answer here without using this class would be too extensive.

Comment: @jspit Thank you. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so this function should work with hours only, not whole dates. In that case I would go for a simpler solution, by not using the `DateTime` class. I also assume the format will always be `'sHH:MM'`, to simplify even further. The `'s'` here stand for *sign*. In that case the smallest time unit will be a minute.

So if we do all real calculations in minutes then we will be fine. This means we should be able to convert time in the `'sHH:MM'` to minutes and visa-versa. I propose the following two functions for this:

```
// requires a valid time in the sHH:MM format, returns minutes of day 
function timeToMinutes($time)
{
    list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':',$time);
    return 60 * $hours + $minutes;
}

// requires an integer, representing minutes, returns time in the sHH:MM format
function minutesToTime($minutes)

{
    return sprintf('%02d', intdiv($minutes, 60)) . ':' . sprintf('%02d', $minutes % 60);
}
```

These are two relatively easy functions, and by using those you can do all the calculations you want. Note that time is always returned without a sign. For adding you would do:

```
function addTime($time1, $time2) 
{
   $minutes = timeToMinutes($time1) + timeToMinutes($time2);
   return minutesToTime($minutes);
}
```

Subtraction now is simple, and will have no problem with negatives, as long as it it stays within 24 hours.

```
function subtractTime($time1, $time2) 
{
   $minutes = timeToMinutes($time1) - timeToMinutes($time2);
   return minutesToTime($minutes);
}
```

Now the testing, the following code:

```
echo timeToMinutes('13:33') . '<br>';
echo minutesToTime(813) . '<br>';
echo addTime('01:00', '13:00')  . '<br>';
echo addTime('-01:00', '13:00')  . '<br>';
echo addTime('14:00', '13:00') . '<br>'; 
echo addTime('-14:00', '13:00') . '<br>';
```

returns:

```
813
13:33
14:00
12:00
27:00
-1:00
```

which is what you wanted. By simplifying things I have made calculating with time, the way you want it, easier, and the code easier to understand and debug.

Comment: Your solution only delivers correct results for times between 00:00 and 23:59. Example: minutesToTime (24 * 60) returns 00:00

Comment: @jspit Can you explain your remark? Which function are you talking about? The allowed range differs from function to function. I also stated: ".... as long as it it stays within 24 hours.". I tried to make these functions so they could answer the question, they are not a general solution.

Comment: Your answer shows the way. The user has to know the limits when copying your solution.
I give 2 examples where these limits are not observed. It is difficult for the user to control this. echo addTime('14:00', '13:00')  . '<br>';  //result 03:00, expect 27:00
echo addTime('-14:00', '13:00')  . '<br>';  //result 23:00, expect -01:00

Comment: @jspit In the question it says: _"I am working with 24h format (00:00, 23:00, etc)."_ So I have attempted to stay within those limits. Therefore 27:00 should be 03:00 and -01:00 should be 23:00.

Comment: Yes, ok. I understand the question differently. The Question from @joaomontes start with "I'm developing a script to measure the working hours." Times over 24 hours and over 100 hours are for working hours often possible.

Comment: Hello @KIKOSoftware, Thank you Very Much. But, yes, jspit is correct, in this case. Could you help me with this?

Comment: @jspit Thank you very much for your Help!! You're actually correct about my needs. Thank you.

Comment: @joaomontes Ok, I start to get it, you simply want to add hours, that's even simpler than what I did. I will correct my answer.

Comment: @jspit Yes, you were right. Thinking about it, it makes sense... 